# how can I use python 3.6 if I have python 3.7?

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to make a discord bot, and I read that I need to have an older version of Python so my code will work. I've tried using "import discord" on IDLE but an error message keeps on coming up. How can I use Python 3.6 and keep Python 3.7 on my Windows 10 computer?

Comment: Install python 3.6 alongside 3.7... Then use a virtual environment. I suggest to install pipenv and then `pipenv install --python 3.6`.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi there are some dependencies that only work for 3.6 , prior or latter ,
now to answer your question, I recommend you to use virtual environment with interpreter as 3.6 or what you can do is install pycharm , at handling environments becomes easier with it

Comment: This might be helpful https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows

Comment: What error message? Have you actually installed discord?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have Python 3.6 now, but I'm getting the error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'. And I use the browser version of Discord

Comment: @ProgGirl you need to install discord for the new interpreter. I am unfamiliar with it in general. However, you should still consider using virtual environments, either through `virtualenv` or `conda` to keep things in order, as recommended by the answers.

Answer (score 2):

i will suggest u using anaconda.

[image]

just create new environment named 'py36'

[image]

then set python version is 3.6

[image]

then run the environment.

if u use pyCharm u can use anaconda's interpreter as the Project's interpreter.

so problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just install it in different folder (e.g. if current one is in C:\Users\noob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37, install 3.6. to C:\Users\noob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36).

Now, when you'll want to run a script, right click the file and under "edit with IDLE" will be multiple versions to choose. Works on my machine :)

Answer (score 0):

- Install in different folder than your old Python 3.6 then update path
- Using Virtualenv and or Pyenv
- Using Docker

Hope it help!